# How to run Django Daphne service on Google Kubernetes Engine and Google Container Registry

Tags: django, google-kubernetes-engine, ubuntu-18.04, docker-container, daphne

## Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install build-essential -y
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app/

# Python
RUN apt-get install python3-pip -y
RUN python3 -m pip install virtualenv
RUN python3 -m virtualenv /env36
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env36
ENV PATH /env36/bin:$PATH
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Start Daphne [8443]
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings
CMD daphne -e ssl:8443:privateKey=/ssl-cert/privkey.pem:certKey=/ssl-cert/fullchain.pem asgi:application

# Open port 8443
EXPOSE 8443
```

Enable Google [IP Alias](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips) in order that we may connect to Google Memorystore/Redis

## Build & Push

```
$ docker build -t [GCR_NAME] -f path/to/Dockerfile .
$ docker tag [GCR_NAME] gcr.io/[GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID]/[GCR_NAME]:[TAG]
$ docker push gcr.io/[GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID]/[GCR_NAME]:[TAG]
```

## Deploy to GKE

```
$ envsubst < k8s.yml > patched_k8s.yml
$ kubectl apply -f patched_k8s.yml
$ kubectl rollout status deployment/[GKE_WORKLOAD_NAME]
```

I configured Daphne on GKE/GCR. If you guys have other solutions, please give me your advice.

Answer (score 1):

`system` is not included in the `Ubuntu:18.04` docker image.

Add an `ENTRYPOINT` to your Dockerfile with commands in `ExecStart` property of `project-daphne.service`.